# How to get the div in which the cursor or caret is placed?

Tags: javascript, element, caret

I have three `contenteditable`divs and I want to know ,in which div the user has placed the cursor or caret through tab key or mouse click,

```
    <div contenteditable="true"></div>
    <div contenteditable="true"></div>
    <div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked out a better solution ,this will need enclosing all the `div` tags that you want to check for the cursor into a parent `div` tag and using the `document.getSelection()` object we can get the id of the div in which the cursor or caret is placed

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div  id=parent>
            <div contenteditable="true" id=1>dddd
            </div>
            <div contenteditable="true" id=2>dddd
            </div>
            <div contenteditable="true" id=3>dddd
            </div>
      </div>
      <input type="label" id="showRes"></input>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

var out=document.getElementById('parent');

function findCursor(){

var x=document.getSelection();
var r=x.getRangeAt(0);
var tempnode=document.createElement("div");
tempnode.setAttribute("id","cursorhook");
r.surroundContents(tempnode);
document.getElementById('showRes').value=tempnode.parentNode.id;
document.getElementById(tempnode.parentNode.id).removeChild(document.getElementById("cursorhook"));


}


out.onkeyup=findCursor;
out.onclick=findCursor;


    </script>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `document.activeElement`. This simply returns whichever element currently has focus on the page. ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.activeElement))

Comment: Up for it works for HTML documents,not accepting coz doesn't work for xml

Answer (score 2):

Use [onfocus](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocus.asp) event which triggers whenever you are focussing an element ...

Example:

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for(var i=0;i<div.length;i++)
   div[i].addEventListener('focus',function(){document.getElementById('showRes').value = this.id;},false);
```

HTML :

```
<div contenteditable="true" id=1></div>
<div contenteditable="true" id=2></div>
<div contenteditable="true" id=3></div>
<input type="label" id="showRes"></input>
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yT5MD/)